# Prove that $\chi_z$ is a character of $\mathbb Z.$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

> Show that for any $z \in \mathbb S^1$ the function $\chi_z$ defined by $n \mapsto z^n$ is a character of $\mathbb Z.$

I am familiar with character of a group representation. Here in order to prove that $\chi_z$ is a character all we need to find out is the underlying group representation of $\mathbb Z$ which is nothing but a group homomorphism $\rho : \mathbb Z \longrightarrow GL(V),$ for some vector space $V$ over some field $\mathbb F.$ I think that if we take the one dimensional representation of $\mathbb Z$ given by $n \mapsto z^n$ then we are through. Is it what is needed to be shown? But I don't understand what's the role of $\mathbb S^1$ here. It seems to me that for any $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ the same reasoning would work. Could anyone please check my argument above and confirm whether it is fine or not?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have a look at this Wikipedia article on the term [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(mathematics)). I think the problem you quote is using the narrow definition referred to there, whereby a character on a group (not a group representation) is just a homomorphism to $S^1$.

Comment: @Rob Arthan that means here character represents a multiplicative character; not a character of a group representation.

Comment: Well the problem that you quote does seem to be about group characters: it makes no mention of representations. What is the context for the problem?

Comment: @Rob Arthan I have found it as an exercise in one of the lecture notes in operator algebras given to us for the purpose of reading course.

Comment: I see. Is there any reason for you to you think the problem is about characters of representations rather than group characters?

Comment: @Rob Arthan the concept of multiplicative characters is not known to me. That's why I thought it be a character of a group representation as I had a course on representation theory in the previous semester. From your link I get to know that there is another notion of characters.  Pardon me please. Sorry for posting this question. Should I delete it?

Comment: There is no need to apologise to me or anyone else on MSE for a perfectly good question. If you have now concluded that your new lecture notes are assuming you know about group characters, then you may feel your question isn't going to help you or other users, so feel free to delete it. That's up to you. Enjoy your course.

Comment: @Rob Arthan another question I want to ask in this regard which is $:$ Can we say that any multiplicative character of $\mathbb Z$ is of the form $\chi_z$ for some $z \in \mathbb S^n\ $?

Comment: Yes (except you mean $\Bbb{S}^1$ not $\Bbb{S}^n)$. This is a high-faluting way of saying that any group homomorphism $\chi$ from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{S}^1$ is uniquely determined by $\chi(1)$ (because $\Bbb{Z}$ is the free group on one generator, namely $1$).

Comment: Respected @Rob Arthan Yes sorry that's a typo. It should be $\mathbb S^1$ instead. Actually my confusion lies in the following argument $:$ According to the definition in wikipedia any multiplicative character $\chi$ of $\mathbb Z$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb C^{\times}.$ So $\chi$ can be determined completely by a non-zero complex number $\chi (1).$ But how do I guarantee that $\chi (1) \in \mathbb S^1\ $? This is where I got stuck. Thanks for your patience.